# How to deploy a django site in ec2 instance with nginx and uwsgi that only allow HTTPS connections?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, devops

I tried many tutorials for the same but none of them worked for me.Please guide me through the correct steps to setup Django.Any guides , tutorials or links will be helpful

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to interpret the content of your question as good as possible... maybe one of these old SO contributions answer your question:

[How to deploy an HTTPS-only site, with Django/nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153875/how-to-deploy-an-https-only-site-with-django-nginx)

[Django + uWSGI + Nginx + SSL - request for working configuration (emphasis on SSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827299/django-uwsgi-nginx-ssl-request-for-working-configuration-emphasis-on-ss)

[setup ssl on nginx for a django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943396/setup-ssl-on-nginx-for-a-django-project)

Otherwise it would be very helpful to rephrase your question.